# I am unable to use Auto Fill method properly in my vba code

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

This code gives me error 1004 and autofill method error If I remove first autofill method then 2nd autofill is working fine otherwise It gives an error,

```
Sub w()

    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    ws1.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ws1.Range("A1").Value = "S.No"
    ws1.Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 204)
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Range("A2").Select ws1.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[1],""000000000000"")&""-""&TEXT(RC[2],""0000"")"
    ws1.Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ws1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Closing Asset Listing-Leading Ledger_Aug-17.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    LastRowclosing = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ws2.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ws2.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[6],""000000000000"")&""-""&TEXT(RC[7],""0000"")"

    ws2.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRowclosing), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A" & LastRowclosing).Select
    ws1.Range("AB2").Select
    ws1.Range("AB2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-27],'[Closing Asset Listing-Leading Ledger_Aug-17.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R13C12,12,0)"

    ws1.Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("AB2" & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to autofill to a range on a different sheet. Your code should be:

```
ws2.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRowclosing), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory It works but my 3rd autofill method still fails after doing the modifications,kindly help with that also

Comment: And also suggest the updation in vlookup if I want my table range until last row with data.

Comment: You can't autofill from AB2 to column L. You may as well just use whole columns with the VLOOKUP.

Comment: Rory, In the same code could you please help me out with the logic that, I need to perform some operations or check some criteria of the result value of V-Lookup function so How can I get it and store it in another variable

Comment: This is not a "one stop shop". If you have a different question, please post it as such. ;)

Comment: It's also a part of this problem only that's why I ask for the suggestion, don't be rude If you don't want to tell then your wish, I have no problem but please talk with etiquettes.

Comment: It may be part of the same code, but it is not the same problem. I don't appreciate being called rude, so I'm afraid I'm done.